# prevent Apache from serving pages with 304 status code

Tags: apache, cakephp, lamp, http-status-code-304

I have a server, LAMP, set up and a CakePHP App. When I request a web page through any web browser, it always replies with a 304 status, serving old pages even after i have changed the page. It seems like the server keeps any previously accessed page in a cache and serves it back to anybody that request it afterwards. E.g: User "X" logs into this system and access the page "home" and logs out. When a different user "Y" logs into the system, he is going to see "X"'s "home" whereas he is supposed to access his home page with his name displayed. Instead he sees it as X has previously accessed it. When I completely delete a resource, say "home" page, it can still be accessed. I have checked and the pages are served with a 304 not modified status code; However I failed to modify this behavior in my apache Settings; I am a newbie and I am out of solutions. Any help would be much appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, I will reply to my own question. I have found a potential cause to this behaviour. My apache settings are fine but my lan has an Apache Traffic Server, which kind of caches some resources, things like images and css files are cached by default. If modification is brought to the file, it is advised to rename it so that the old file is not served. For the web pages, I forced their non caching by adding the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

As I was using cakePHP, I also added the following lines in my beforeFilter method of AppController file ([asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804628/cakephp-caching-issue-when-redirecting-back-to-same-page)):

```
function beforeFilter() {

    /**
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804628/cakephp-caching-issue-when-redirecting-back-to-same-page
     */

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

}
```

I hope it helps someone.